# Multiple versions of a Word document in the same file

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

Waaaay back long ago when Microsoft Word allowed us to save multiple versions of a document in the same file, I did that. Years later, I've upgraded to Office 2021, and now I want to get those earlier versions of the doc. Likely I can't do that in Word 2021 since Microsoft discontinued the versioning function, but I'm going to ask anyway.

Is there a way I can extract those previous versions in Word 2021? I've also got access to Word 2016 if that helps.

Or do I have to find an old version of Word to get them? If so, how far back do I have to go?

Here's the message I get when I try to update the Word doc from .doc to .docx in case anyone needs it for context:

`"This file contains multiple versions of the document but word no longer stores multiple versions of a document in a single file. Do you want to continue to save this file?"`

Google isn't helping. In fact, half the results I get about "version" refer to the version of Word (or Office), not the versioning function in Word.

Thanks, everyone!

**Edit for progress:** I've found Word 2000 (thanks to Charles below). I loaded the documents in Word 2000 and loaded them. When I went to File->Versions, I found that there were no versions in the docs after all. However, when I go Word 2021 and Save As, I get the following message:

`This file contains multiple versions of the document, but Word no longer stores multiple versions of a document in a single file. If you save this file, previous versions of the document will be lost.

Do you want to continue to save this file?`

Are there indeed other versions of the file in there that Word 2000 can't find? Is there a solution to digging up these older versions, or is Word 2021 making a mistake and there really are no older versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Microsoft 365 and OneDrive. That saves entire versions, not simply changes staged.

I believe the last version of Word that had versioning built into the files was Word 2000 or 2002 but I am unsure.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Charles! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Got a newer issue, but I added the details above.

Comment: I don't any longer have access to Word 2000. I would suggest saving a sample .doc file that is giving this message on OneDrive or Dropbox and including a link to the document in your question. Someone else may be able to look at it. Note that some error messages generated by Word have little or nothing to do with what they say. **Note also: The reason Microsoft discontinued the versioning was that it had a tendency to corrupt or mess up documents.**